# How can you set a property of a UIViewController that is about to load in a UITabBarController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm loading up a UITabBarController via a Storyboard as follows:

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"EventsAdmin" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:[sb instantiateInitialViewController] animated:YES];
```

The initial view controller is the uitabbarviewcontroller however I'd like to set a property on each of the view controllers that is loaded. How can I do this?

Comment: You want to set a property on each of the viewControllers loaded inside the uitabbarviewcontroller ? Please explain.

Comment: @AbhishekMukherjee exactly.

Comment: All the viewControllers loaded inside the tab bar controller can have as many properties as they want in their corresponding viewController classes. Whats the exact problem you are facing ?

Comment: @AbhishekMukherjee I want to set the property of a sub viewcontroller before presenting it.

Comment: Why not just setting the property of the destination controller in prepareForSegue method?

Comment: @AbhishekMukherjee because it's the UITabBarViewController returned in the prepareForSegue method.

Comment: You can access the other view controllers through the property "viewControllers" of the tabBarController which returns an array of all the view controllers represented in the tab bar.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this the following way:

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"EventsAdmin" bundle:nil];

id vc = [sb instantiateInitialViewController];
[self.navigationController pushViewController: vc animated: YES];

if ([vc isKindOfClass: [UITabBarController class]])
{
    for (UIViewController *controller in [(UITabBarController *)vc viewControllers])
    {
       // set your property
    }
}
```

In the loop you should check if controller is an instance of the view controller class you want to modify the property of.

Comment: so this means that UITabBarController initializes all sub view controllers immediately?

Comment: That's a good question. Probably they are getting initialized with the tabbarcontroller within the initWithCoder: method. As long as they are set through the interface builder

Answer (score 0):

Or.. You could declare a protocol and give these modal viewControllers a property of type

```
`IBOutlet id <myProtocol> delegate
```

And hook these up to the root view controller in the storyboard.  Then the modal viewControllers can query the delegate from their viewWillAppearAnimated: 
Then in your rootViewController you'll have (as part of myProtocol) a

```
-(void)setMyStuffUp:(UIViewController *)modalViewcontroller{


if ([modalViewController isKindOfClass:[viewControllerOne class]]){

//set stuff

}elseIf ( etc == etc){

//setOtherStuff..

}



}
```